# C++ COM с помощью fstream

Tags: c++, arduino, fstream, com-порт

Читаю данные из ком порта делал это с помощью readFile С которым раньше серьёзно никогда не работал, код просто непонятный. Потом подумал если это всё равно технология чтения файлов, почему бы не использовать привычную мне fstream.

Порт открылся, устройство отреагировало на это начало слать данные, но в консоль ничего не выводиться. как организовать чтение с ком порта используя библиотеку fstream

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    ifstream in("COM3");
        if(in) 
            cout<<"open ok";
        else
            cout<<"open noo";


        if(in)
        {
            char t;
            in.read(&t,sizeof(t));
            cout<<t;
        }

    }
```

программа останавливается на строке  in.read(&t,sizeof(t)); и не реагирует на входные данные.

Comment: Нет возможности читать fstream

Comment: Но он же открыл порт.

Comment: а stdio можно использовать для чтения из ком?

Comment: Можно через буст и через windows.h. Бустом проще но через windows тоже пойдет. Если там возникнут какие то вопросы пишите. Как я считаю достаточно сильно разбираюсь в данной теме.

Comment: Попробуйте ему flush сделать...

Comment: Может надо стрим с ключем binary открыть?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы читать файл по старинке по-байтно нужно задать опцию:

```
ifstream in("COM3",std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score -3):

Для работы с COM-портом его следует настроить после открытия файла.

Рекомендую почитать мою статью [Host-клиент Arduino на C (Linux)](https://sites.google.com/site/vanyambauseslinux/arduino/host-klient-arduino-na-s-linux).